# Can I use two ultrasound sensors at a time?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

Is there a way to use two ultrasound sensors on a Mindstorms NXT without them interfering with each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

theres a *single shot mode* (at least when using NXC, NXT-G is very limited in fuctionality) for ultrasonic sensors. if you use that and don't read from two sensors at the exact same time, you can pass around interferences. to read more about that, please take a look at:

- http://www.mindsensors.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=134
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/roboticstroubleshooting/thread/81a4680d-20a7-46bc-bdba-e7041566c93c